Parsing through XML when xsi:type="address">
How can I get any of tags inside sf:Address (ex. city, country, etc.) in below XML using XSLT?
(This is the query response I got from Salesforce CRM using SOAP Generator XSL)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <LimitInfoHeader>
            <limitInfo>
                <current>331</current>
                <limit>5000000</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
            </limitInfo>
        </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <queryResponse>
            <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>User</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id>005cW000003aMnlQAE</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Id>005cW000003aMnlQAE</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Username>aatest</sf:Username>
                    <sf:FirstName>abc</sf:FirstName>
                    <sf:LastName>d</sf:LastName>
                    <sf:Title xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sf:Phone>1234567890</sf:Phone>
                    <sf:Email>abc.d@web.com</sf:Email>
                    <sf:MobilePhone xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sf:Address xsi:type="address">
                        <latitude xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <longitude xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <city>Hyderabad</city>
                        <country>India</country>
                        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
                        <postalCode>500081</postalCode>
                        <state>Andhra Pradesh</state>
                        <stateCode>AP</stateCode>
                        <street>Hi tech city</street>
                    </sf:Address>
                </records>
                <size>1</size>
            </result>
        </queryResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> 

I tried using <xsl:value-of select="//sf:Address/city"/> but could not get the desired city value.
I expect the output to be Hyderabad.

Please post your attempt as an executable stylesheet - see: [mcve]. Note that the city element is also in a namespace, so the expression //sf:Address/city will select nothing unless you are using an XSLT 2.0 + processor AND you have declared "urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" as the XPath default namespace. I also don't see what the xsi:type has to do with this: is there another element named sf:Address whose xsi:type is NOT address?

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

what did you get?....anything?
